# Java threadpool functionality

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to make a program with a limited amount of threads (currently using newFixedThreadPool) but I have the problem that all threads get created from start, filling up memory at alarming rate.

I wish to prevent this. Threads should only be created shortly before they are executed.

e.g.: I call the program and instruct it to use 2 threads in the pool. The program should create & launch the first 2 Threads immediately (obviously), create the next 2 to wait for the previous 2, and at that point wait until one or both of the first 2 ended executing.

I thought about extending executor or FixedThreadPool or such. However I have no clue on how to start there and doubt it is the best solution. Easiest would have my main Thread sleeping on intervals, which is not really good either...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the details in your post...

> I call the program and instruct it to use 2 threads in the pool. The program should create & launch the first 2 Threads immediately (obviously), **create the next 2 to wait for the previous 2**, and at that point wait until one or both of the first 2 ended executing.

Your problem is much more about synchronizing tasks execution than in fact pooling threads. From what you say here, you want to have **2 threads** executing any number of tasks; if you don't want to have 100 jobs running at the same time, don't create a 100 threads pool...

I would suggest either using a BlockingQueue to control your Runnables, or create a 2 threads pool using a ThreadPoolExecutor, and feed it all your tasks. It will execute them when threads are available.

Does that make sense with what you try to achieve here?

Comment: It makes more sense. But thanks to your answer I have landed on the producer / consumer method, which is exactly what I need: 1 producer reading the file, and x (to be defined) consumers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried taking a look at [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) ? Using the right constructor parameters, you could easily tweak the number and keep-alive time of the created threads.

Comment: Yes, and for him, he needs to set the core-thread number to 0.

Comment: I don't see how that changes the situation actually... In my main thread I'm reading from a file, and according to some content in the line I'm reading, I create a thread and add it to the executor. In this constructor I add the read lines, so the object has them. In result I'm actually stuffing the file in-memory, but larger files will result in a huge performance hit and/or too little memory...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should manipulate the thread pool implementation. If you create the threads shortly before execution, you lose the main benefit of the pool, that recycles your threads.

Maybe you should reduce the maximum number of threads in the pool. If you instruct the pool to create too many of them, the total out-of-heap memory used for their stack spaces will consume all available memory. I assume that this is the kind of OutOfMemoryError you have (?).

Comment: I haven't had the error yet. But I predict it will. At some point the program should work with larger and larger datasets and I doubt the machine's memory will always be able to hold it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at this from a performance perspective, then it's best to take the hit in memory when you first start up the application than constantly get bombarded with allocating and deallocating memory while the program is running.

If it's using too much memory when you start the application, then it will still be too much memory later. You should throttle down the size of the thread pool.

There are additional benefits to using a thread pool, such as if you lose a thread along the way, the thread pool will automatically create a new one to replace it, keeping your thread pool at a constant size.

If this isn't the type of benefit that you're looking for, then you may wish to handle the threads in memory manually, and avoid the thread pool.

Comment: I guess I'll give my own handling a shot. Although that sounds like a lot of work keeping track of the number of threads and all. Also, it still requires sleep moments to wait for threads to end. Is there a way to "wait" for several threads without ThreadPool?